Съемный диск не отображается в проводнике
Подключаю Съемный жесткий диск к ноуту, в дисковых устройствах есть, а в управлении дисков, как и в проводнике его нет, что с этим делать не понимаю, раньше видел, но во время игры резко перестал, ошибок в диспетчере устройств никаких не показывает
